# Nuances of meaning between "venir tout juste de" and "venir à peine de"?

Tags: sens

It's tempting to think that they are just interchangeable, but I've realised...

> {I'd say}: Je viens **tout juste** de l’apprendre, mais il semblerait ...
>
> {but I wouldn't say}: Je viens **à peine** de l’apprendre, mais il semblerait ...

In another instance:

> {I'm slightly more likely to say}:  Bien sur, tu n’allais pas me demander de sortir avec moi alors qu’on venait **à peine** de se rencontrer!
>
> {rather than}: Bien sur, tu allais pas me demander de sortir avec moi alors qu’on venait **tout juste** de se rencontrer!

The thing is ... I'm not quite sure why I feel the way I do about all this. How exactly do you determine when to use one or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J’aurais été tenté de croire que les deux étaient équivalents, mais il existe au moins quelques cas où ils diffèrent, et ces cas sont intéressants pour tenter de cerner la nuance particulière de l’un et de l’autre.

> **J’ai tout juste compris la démonstration** → je l’ai comprise, mais j’ai dû fournir un effort et j’aurais très bien pu ne pas réussir à établir quelques liens qui s’avérèrent cruciaux à la compréhension.
>   **J’ai à peine compris la démonstration** → j’ai compris qu’il s’agissait d’une démonstration, j’en ai compris quelques éléments, mais le gros de l’information m’a échappé.

Les deux exemples donnés dans le message original font cependant une utilisation temporelle des expressions (ce qui n’est pas le cas de mon exemple), et chacune de leurs deux versions est selon moi correcte et utilisable. La nuance me semble très subtile: tous deux indiquent un court laps de temps, mais peut-être que **tout juste** insiste un peu plus sur la brièveté de la durée écoulée (allusion à un passé très récent), et **à peine** un peu plus sur une certaine insuffisance de cette durée (tout est nouveau, on réserve un jugement final pour plus tard).

Un cas, tout de même, où la différence pourrait modifier substantiellement l’interprétation d’un auditeur:

> **Je viens tout juste de terminer mes études** → Je suis maintenant disponible au travail, diplôme en poche, la vie professionnelle m’attend!
>   **Je viens à peine de terminer mes études** → Je suis diplômé, mais je n’ai peut-être pas toutes les qualifications que confère l’expérience, soyez indulgent...

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I don't feel any difference. I'd use both indifferently.

That being said, maybe your feeling is:

1) *Tout juste* has the idea of *despite*

> **Malgré le fait que** je vienne tout juste de l'apprendre, il semblerait que...
>
> *Despite* I've just heard about it...

2) *à peine* has the idea of *because*

> **Parce qu**’on venait à peine de se rencontrer, alors tu n'allais pas me demander...
>
> It's *because* we've just met than you can't ask me...